# The WordPress Gallery, Grabbing The Link and Images?

Tags: images, gallery

I have created a template for gallery named image.php which allows me to create a  news website style image gallery that can be embedded in posts.  But I need two more things to make this complete.

- First, I want to know **how to create a text link to the first image in a gallery**, rather than displaying thumbnails for the gallery as the built-in [gallery] shortcode currently does.
  For example, check out "click here to start" on this page: http://www.businessinsider.com/android-vs-iphone-debate-quotes-2011-12
- Secondly, if anybody knows **how to generate a list of all the images in a gallery** which I can add to my image.php file that would be great to have so I could use it to create a slider on the bottom of each page featuring an image with the other images in the gallery.

Comment: Text link to the first image? The example you've given is an image containing text. And you want to fetch all the images from the current post gallery right?

Comment: There's also a text link at the bottom of the article.  And yes, fetch the images from the current post gallery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attachments in a gallery are their own posts, with some special settings. To get a list of all the attachments for a given post, you basically just create a new query and specify the post parent and attachment type.

```
$gallery_images = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    )
);
```

You can then loop through this query in the same way as any other loop to access those images.

```
while ( $gallery_images->have_posts() ) : $gallery_images->the_post();
    the_title(); 
    the_content(); 
    the_permalink();
    whatever();
endwhile;

// always reset the post data at the end of any non-main loop
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Creating a text link to one of those images would be done the wp_get_attachment_link function. For a text only link, use "none" as the size parameter.

```
echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment_id, 'none', true, false, 'Link Text' );
```

Comment: The above code is not grabbing the other images for me.

Comment: I use code exactly like that on many sites, for many galleries. It works fine, but you'll obviously need to customize it for your particular setup. The main WP_Query though is basically correct and should work in a standard Loop.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2eSNW0Le Did I do this correctly?  Lines 74 to 94.

Comment: No, that looks like you're putting this into a single image attachment page or something. In which case you should have `'post_parent' => $parent->ID,`. Also code isn't copy-pasta, you need to modify it to be specific to your own needs. The fact that you left `whatever();` in there kinda indicates that you don't really know what you're doing. I was trying to show you *how* it works, you still have to write your own code to do what you want.

Comment: I definitely don't know what I'm doing with PHP.

Comment: @Otto, does your code still work? I'm trying to make it work on my custom post type single page, unfortunately I have absolutely no idea why `$post->ID` displays different images than my gallery and when i go with `$parent->ID` it lists EVERYTHING from my Media Library. The same goes for `$page->ID`. I've checked `$post->ID` and looks like it returns the right ID so I have no idea what the issue might be? Here's my recent question about that: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125781/changing-gallery-images-size